# VSIX extension for workflow - what type of Asset?

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working on a Visual Studio extension which will contain some workflows for database and code generation. One assembly named `MyActivities` contains some implementations of `NativeActivity` which are then used in XAML workflows like this:

```
<Sequence xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyActivities;assembly=MyActivities">
    <my:MyActivity CsdlInput="[Csdl]" SsdlOutput="[Ssdl]"/>
    ...
```

This is very similar to what the [Entity Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) does for Visual Studio 2010. However, our extension will be for VS2012.

Now I need a way to link this assembly to Visual Studio, so that it's available when the workflow executes. I tried creating a VSIX extension and adding the assembly as an Asset. I tried different Asset types, for example `Assembly` or `MefComponent`, but none worked. Visual Studio keeps telling me:

```
`Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:MyActivities;assembly=MyActivities}MyActivity'.
```

What kind of Asset do I need to create a simple VSIX extension that installs my assembly so Visual Studio can use it?

Comment: Ignoring the VSIX question for a moment, where would normally have to install this binary in order for this to work? The GAC?

Comment: Thanks @JasonMalinowski, problem is I don't know where such assemblies are installed. But I found a solution which makes the installation unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I want:

In the project that uses the activity workflow, just add a reference to the assembly that contains the activity code (`MyActivities` in my case).

So maybe it's not necessary (or not possible) to create a VSIX extension that does what I want. But adding the reference is fine, too.